# How do I lock my bootloader again?

Tags: rooting, bootloader, motorola-moto-g, unrooting, bootloader-lock

I tried to root my Moto G3; but I was unsuccessful. Now my phones boots with this warning.

[image: Bootloader Unlocked Warning on Boot]

I am sick of seeing this on boot screen. How do I disable it? Seems like I need to lock the bootloader again. How do I do that? I'm completely blank.

Comment: You don't need to; flash a boot logo file via fastboot to get rid of the warning. Also, try rooting properly again, it's not as hard as you think.

Comment: The fastboot command is:  fastboot flash logo logo.bin

Answer (score 2):

First, I want to tell you that relocking the bootloader will NOT get rid of that message... On the Moto G3, once the bootloader has been unlocked that message will always appear, forever. That being said, you can flash a custom boot logo to cover the warning. I will explain how to relock the bootloader and fix the logo though.

To successfully relock the bootloader on a Moto device, you must flash a complete stock firmware image via fastboot that is of the same or newer revision than you have installed, you cannot downgrade to relock. Firmware images are available [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/2015-moto-g/general/index-moto-g-factory-firmware-images-t3169639) and vary by exact model. Once you have that unzipped and in your fastboot directory, perform the following commands:

```
fastboot oem lock begin  
fastboot flash partition gpt.bin  
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img  
fastboot flash logo logo.bin  
fastboot flash boot boot.img  
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img  
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0  
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1  
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2  
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3  
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.4  
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.5  
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.6  
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.7  
fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.8  
fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin  
fastboot erase modemst1   
fastboot erase modemst2   
fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn  
fastboot erase cache   
fastboot erase userdata  
fastboot erase customize  
fastboot erase clogo  
fastboot oem lock    
fastboot reboot
```

Note that the number of sparcechunks can vary by model and Android version from 5-11 pieces, but what you flash must match the firmware image you have. If any piece fails, the bootloader will not lock.

Once this is done, you will have a completely stock device and a relocked bootloader, with a nice Bootloader Unlocked warning screen. As I said, once the bootloader has been unlocked, it cannot be restored to it's original condition in any way we know of.

To get rid of the screen (but not the delay or vibration, we can't get rid of that) you can flash a patched logo.bin file in fastboot. This can be done even with a locked bootloader. This can be done by flashing the logo.bin file from [this](https://basketbuild.com/filedl/devs?dev=Alberto97&dl=Alberto97/osprey/unlocked_logo.zip) ZIP file with the command:

fastboot flash logo logo.bin

And the warning screen will disappear. The ZIP file can also be flashed in it's entirety via TWRP recovery instead.

All of this may not be relevant, since rooting this device is very simple, since that wasn't your question I will not answer it here, but I will point you to [my thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/2015-moto-g/general/guide-how-to-root-moto-g-2015-model-t3448572) which may be of assistance if you want to attempt rooting again. Note that the logo.bin file I reference above can be flashed on a stock or modified system to get rid of the warning, your bootloader does not have to be locked to get rid of the warning.

Comment: What may be the consequences if I let the bootloader unlocked.

Comment: @Ajay The "consequence" is your bootloader is unlocked, meaning an unscrupulous individual who gets physical access to your device may be able to bypass any security you have and access the device by flashing a customer kernel or ROM. Honestly, there is nearly zero chances of that occurring unless you are a high value target (politician, public figure, etc), and even then the chances are infinitesimally low. Essentially locking the bootloader gives some protection from tampering to critical startup processes of the device and the bootloader should never be locked on a device that is not stock.

Answer (score 2):

> I am sick of seeing this on boot screen. How do I disable it?

I too was annoyed by the hysterical warning. As other users answered already, while relocking wouldn't get rid of or skip it, the screen image can be easily reflashed back to stock.

I want to expand on this and show how this screen can be given a custom boot screen, way less alarming and fitting your custom rom.

Build [github.com/eriktim/moto-bootlogo](https://github.com/eriktim/moto-bootlogo) and either pull the logo partition from ones own device..

```
adb shell su -c "dd if=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/logo of=/sdcard/logo.bin count=1 bs=634418"
adb pull /sdcard/logo.bin .
```

..or download and trust an existing `logo.bin` within the original animation of your devices in the [moto boot animation collection](https://github.com/bmaupin/motorola-boot-animations/releases).

```
$ moto-bootlogo -i logo.png logo.bin
Created 'logo-custom.bin'
Parsing header of 'logo-custom.bin'.
..
Found 3 images.

$ adb reboot bootloader
```

then flash the logo partition

```
$ fastboot flash logo logo-custom.bin
```

and gone is the bootloader warning.

Answer (score -2):

`fastboot oem lock` should do it.

Comment: That doesn't work on the G3... I'll answer in a couple minutes